# How to override method of function field in odoo?

Tags: function, methods, field, odoo, extend

I was getting traceback error while filling timesheet. After R&D I came to know that it was the issue of Odoo’s code it self. I compared code with the latest one and found the issue.

**The Problem:**

The method is called from function field. I have overridden it successfully but the problem is, after overriding it, it is calling first the original method of Odoo and after that, it is calling my overridden method. That’s why I am facing the same traceback error.

**Here is default code:**

```py
def _get_task(self, cr, uid, id, context=None):
   res = []
   for line in self.pool.get('account.analytic.line').search_read(cr,uid,[('task_id', '!=', False),('id','in',id)], context=context):
       res.append(line['task_id'][0])
   return res
```

**Here is my overridden code after bug fixed by Odoo:**

```py
def _get_task(self, cr, uid, id, context=None):
   res = []
   for line in self.pool.get('account.analytic.line').search_read(cr, uid,[('task_id', '!=', False), ('id', 'in', id)], ['task_id'], context=context):
       res.append(line['task_id'][0])
   return res
```

The only difference between these two is the [‘task_id’] which is added in the search_read method.

Can anybody help me out regarding it?

Comment: override the field definition change the function name. it may work for you

Answer (score 1):

Functions of function fields are called from within the field "definition". Since you never changed that definition, the field doesn't know anything about your function. Just define the field, you're change the function for, new. But care about defining it completly, because in the old API that was necessary.